# Prove $\sum_{i=n}^{2n}i=\frac{3}{2}n(n+1)$ using induction

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction

> Prove that $$\sum_{i=n}^{2n}i=\frac{3}{2}n(n+1)$$ usind induction.

---

Base step: for $n=1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{2\cdot1}i=1+2=3$, and $\frac{3}{2}1(1+1)=\frac322=3$, so it is true for $n=1$.

My problem starts when trying to prove the inductive step: $$\sum_{i=h}^{2h}i=\frac{3}{2}h(h+1)\implies\sum_{i=h+1}^{2(h+1)}i=\frac{3}{2}(h+1)(h+2).$$ I have read that it has to be: \begin{align}\sum_{i=h+1}^{2(h+1)}i&=\sum_{i=h+1}^{2h+2}i\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{i=h}^{2h}(i)}_{\text{Hypothesis}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{2}}_{(*)}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}h(h+1)+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{2}}_{(*)}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}h(h+1)+\bigl((h+1)+2(h+1)\bigr)\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\frac32h^2+\frac92h+3\\
&=\frac32(h+1)(h+2)\end{align}

but I think $(*)$ has no sense.

But I am not able to write it in a nice way because I think it has to be: $$(*)=\sum_{i=h+1}^{2}(2i+2)=\bigl(2(h+1)+2\bigr)+\bigl(2(2(h+1)+2)\bigr),$$ which is not right.

So my questions are:

1. Is $(*)$ correct? What has to be inside the summation i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^2\square$? Why the initial value is $i=1$ but not $i=h+1$?
2. Where is my mistake?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=h+1}^{2h+2}i & = \sum_{i=h+1}^{2h}i+\underbrace{(2h+1)+(2h+2)}_{\text{ the } 2h+1 \, \& \, 2h+2 \, \text{terms}} \\
& = \color{red}{h}+\sum_{i=h+1}^{2h}i+(2h+1)+(2h+2)\color{blue}{-h}\\
& = \underbrace{\sum_{i=\color{red}{h}}^{2h}i}_{\text{hypothesis expression}}+(2h+1)+(2h+2)\color{blue}{-h}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}h(h+1)+3h+3.
\end{align*}
Now you can finish off.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n + 2} k
= \left(\sum_{k = n}^{2n + 2} k\right) - n
= \left(\sum_{k = n}^{2n} k\right) + \left(2n + 1 + 2n + 2\right) - n
= \left(\sum_{k = n}^{2n} k\right) + 3n + 3.
$$
Explanation: 
In the very first expression my first summand is the $n + 1$-th term. After the equality sign I begin at the $n$-th term, which is not in the first expression, so I have to subtract it again.

For the next equality, it's the same procedure, only the other way around. In the second term, I add until the $2n + 2$-th term. I only want to add until $2n$, so I have to subtract the $2n + 2$-th and $2n + 1$-th term. Note that the $j$-th term of the series is always $j$.

Answer (score 2):

> $$\sum_{i=h+1}^{2(h+1)}i=\sum_{i=h+1}^{2h+2}i=\underbrace{\sum_{i=h}^{2h}(i)}_{\text{Hypothesis}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{2}}_{(*)}$$

It looks you misunderstand the summation notation. Here are some more details (in expanded forms):
$$\sum_{i=h+1}^{2(h+1)}i=\sum_{i=\color{blue}{h+1}}^{\color{red}{2h+2}}i=(\color{blue}{h+1})+(h+2)+\cdots +(2h)+(2h+1)+(\color{red}{2h+2})=\\
\color{green}{h}+(h+1)+(h+2)+\cdots +(2h)+(2h+1)+(2h+2)-\color{green}h=\\
\color{blue}{h}+(h+1)+(h+2)+\cdots +(\color{red}{2h})+(2h+1)+(2h+2)-h=\\
\sum_{i=\color{blue}h}^{\color{red}{2h}}i+(3h+3)=\frac32h(h+1)+3(h+1)=\frac32(h+1)(h+2).$$
Note:

1) In the summations above, the sum is taken from $\color{blue}{blue}$ to $\color{red}{red}$.

2) In line 2, the number $\color{green}h$ is added and subtracted to complete the sum from $\color{blue}h$ to $\color{red}{2h}$, which is needed for the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

You should have said $$\sum_{i=h+1}^{2h+2}i=\left(\sum_{i=h}^{2h}i\right)-h+(2h+1)+(2h+2)$$

Comment: Thanks! I have never descompose a summation wrt the initial values i.e. $i=h+1$. So my questions are: 1) How do you go from $i=h+1$ to $i=h$? 2) Why there is a $-h+(2h+1)+(2h+2)$?

Comment: In general with integers $a<b<c<d,$ $$\sum_{i=a}^d f(i)=\sum_{i=a}^b f(i) + \sum_{i=b+1}^c f(i) + \sum_{i=c+1}^d f(i);$$ try writing out with some small values of $h$ to see

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Denoting the sums $S_n$  and  $S_{n+1}$, just look at how they begin and end:
\begin{alignat}{3}
S_n &= {} &n&+{}&(n+1)+(n+2)+\dots &+2n \\
S_{n+1} &={} &&\phantom{+{}}&(n+1)+(n+2)+\dots &+2n +(2n+1)+(2n+2),
\end{alignat}
so that we have the relation
$$S_{n+1}=S_n -n+(2n+1)+(2n+2)=S_n+3(n+1).$$
Can you end the computation?